# Update model value django (boolean field) through button HTML

Tags: django, django-models

How can i change model value from models.py using html button, so this is my models.py and my main.html

models.py

```
class Note(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=3000, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    clear = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

main.html

```
<div class="col">
{% if note.clear %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-note">Unclear</button>
{% else %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-note">Clear</button>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

I want to change that `"clear"` value to true or false every time I click the button `"btn-note"`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is like:

#### views.py

```
def toggle_note_clear(request):
    note = get_object_or_404(Note, pk=request.GET.get('note_id'))
    note.clear = not note.clear
    note.save()
    return redirect('notes:detail') # you should change that with the name of your view
```

#### main.html

```
<div class="col">
   <!-- make sure you are using the correct name url here -->
   <a href="{% url 'notes:toggle_clear' %}?note_id={{note.pk}}"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-note">
   {% if note.clear %}
     Unclear
   {%else%}
     Clear
   {%end%}
   </a>

</div>
```

Don't forget to update your URL with the fresh view you have created above.